# Disable Value in multiple dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have many dropdownlist and I want if I choose a value i want to disable it in other dropdown for example if i choose Test in select1 and Test 2 in select2 I should have Test 1 and Test 2 disabled in select3

Here my script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var player_selected = [];

    function checkPlayerSelected(){
        player_selected = [];
        $('select').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != "0"){
                player_selected.push($(this).val());

            }
        });
    }

    $('select').change(function(){
        checkPlayerSelected();
        console.log(player_selected);
        $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
            if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), player_selected)){
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);   
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="select1" name="select1">
    <option value="0">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select2">
    <option value="0">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select3" name="select3">
    <option value="0">No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var player_selected = [];

    function checkPlayerSelected(){
        player_selected = [];
        $('select').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != "0"){
                player_selected.push($(this).val());

            }
        });
    }

    $('select').change(function(){
        checkPlayerSelected();
        console.log(player_selected);
        $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled', true);
            if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), player_selected) >-1){
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);   
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to enable again if I change a value but I still have a problem when i choose Test - Test 2 - Test 3 in the second dropdown "Test" is enable i don t know why

Comment: please clear what you wanted to do

Comment: your code already done that I think

Comment: You explained what the code should do, but didn't explain what the problem actually was. That's an important part so people know what to look for

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close except that `&.inArray()` returns either the array index or `-1` if not found.

You need to compare to `-1` in your `if` since `0` is a valid index but will return false in the conditional

Change

```
if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), player_selected))
```

To

```
if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), player_selected) >-1)
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h8cpotLg/)**</kbd>

Comment: But what if user change the  value again? :)

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah...good point. Think I'll let OP digest that one in round 2

Comment: That s i wanted to but yes i think there is a mistake on my code if want to change value

Comment: Note you need to reset anything you disabled previously also if it is changed

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated my code but still have a problem :(

Comment: what is the problem? Also update the jsfiddle I created and save update on it so it can be shared

Comment: and the problem? I can probably find it but you should be explaing your issues better